# How to print debug messages to stdout, but not into log file, in Ansible when log_path is set?

Tags: ansible

I have `log_path` set in `ansible.cfg` because I want Ansible to log all output by default. I have some `debug` tasks that print messages to `stdout` for the user to see.

Is there a way to print something to `stdout` ***without*** logging it to the file (while still logging most other things)?

`no_log: true` suppresses `stdout` as well.

Answer (score 1):

According the documentation [`log_plays` callback – write playbook output to log file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/log_plays_callback.html), leading to [Ansible Galaxy - `community.general collection`](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ui/repo/published/community/general/) and finally the [Source Code of the Callback Plugin `log_plays.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/callback/log_plays.py) it doesn't seems so out-of-box. Whereby the [`log_folder`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/environment_variables.html#envvar-ANSIBLE_LOG_FOLDER) is configurable, other behavior is not.

It is possible in a Custom Callback Plugin version by adding some logic there, handling maybe `check_mode` like in the [`default` callback – default Ansible screen output](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/default_callback.html), [`default.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py).

> ***Is there a way to print something to `stdout` without logging it to the file (while still logging most other things)?***

Yes, in example just by tweaking the `log_plays.py` with an additional

```python
    def log(self, result, category):
        data = result._result
        if isinstance(data, MutableMapping):
            if 'debug' in result._task.action:
                # avoid logging debug output
                data = 'omitted'
```

in order to suppress only any output from the debug module. It would result into a log file output of

```
Oct 15 2023 17:20:00 - log_plays.yml -  - debug - OK - omitted
```

instead of

```
Oct 15 2023 17:25:00 - log_plays.yml -  - debug - OK - {"msg": "Debug output", "changed": false, "_ansible_verbose_always": true, "_ansible_no_log": false}
```